# Remove a selected value from multi ng select angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I have 2 ng select with multiple set as true. When ng select box **A** is selected it will load the data for ng select **B**. So when a value is unselected from A the options coming under the removed option in **A** will be removed from **B**.

### What I'm trying to do

Let's say in **A** optionC and optionD are selected. So in **B** data for optionC and optionD will be loaded. In **B** I select optionC1, optionD2, optionD3. Here if the optionC is removed from **A** the corresponding options will be removed in **B** also except the selected value optionC1. How can I remove the selected value?

Any help would be appreciated.

**ng select - A**

```
 section = [
           { id: 1, name: food},
           { id: 15, name: stationary},
           { id: 18, name: clothes}
    ]
```

**ng select - B**

```
subsection = [
   { id: 1, type_id:1, name: pizza },
   { id: 2, type_id:1, name: sushi },
   { id: 10, type_id:2, name: book},
   { id: 11, type_id:2, name: pencil},
   { id: 14, type_id:3, name: tshirt},
   { id: 15, type_id:3, name: shoes}
 ]
```

**HTML**

```
<ng-select [multiple]="true" #section [items]="section" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id"
                                formControlName="section" (change)="loadSubSection()">
                                <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index">
                                    <b>{{item.name}}</b>
                                </ng-template>
                            </ng-select>

<ng-select [multiple]="true" #subsection [items]="subSection" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id"
                                    formControlName="subSection">
                                    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index">
                                        <b>{{item.name}}</b>
                                    </ng-template>
                                </ng-select>
```

**TS**

```
loadSubSection(){
const sec = this.section.selectedValues;
const select = this.subsection.selectedValues;
<<Code to fetch data>>
const data = <<fetched data>>
this.selected = select.filter(function (cItem) {
      return data.find(function (aItem) {
        return cItem.name === aItem.name;
      });
    });

this.subsection.select(this.selected);
}
```

Comment: Please tell me how I can improve my question before downvoting

Comment: what do you mean by type_id? is it the id of the items in first select list?